# CryptoJS decrypt AES returns empty

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptojs

I have trouble decrypting data in CryptoJS. After decrypting the data it returns an empty string
Here is my code:

[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkpYs.png)

```
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(dataa[5]);
  var key = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
  key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
  var decrypted =  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(dataa[1], key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
  decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  console.log(decrypted);
  alert(decrypted);
```

The alert returns an empty string. Dataa[5] is the IV and dataa[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkpYs.png) is the data that has to decrypted.
After the CryptoJS.AES.decrypt the variable decrypted is already empty.
I am new to CryptoJS and do not understand why it wont work.

dataa[ 1 ] = gXodEwQf2Mk+ZW9RDiktNw

dataa[ 5 ] = s/D0LaJK1SwL9pgF/r1DAQ==

Comment: what are te values of data[5] and data[1]

Comment: @cmgchess i edited the post so you can now see the values of data 1 and 5

Comment: Both values are Base64 encoded, i.e. you have to Base64 decode the IV: `var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('s/D0LaJK1SwL9pgF/r1DAQ==');` Regarding the ciphertext no change is necessary, because CryptoJS can handle Base64 encoded ciphertexts. The plaintext is: _POG u 3 v IOs_